# Updating values in cli/c++ array<Object^> causes extensive Garbage Collection

Tags: arrays, garbage-collection, c++-cli

The Method below is used to transport native data into managed data
structures. The AppendDataToChannel method does assign the created arrays
to bigger structures.

What i am seeing now is that this methods execution time is 50% garbage
collection. As time is very critical for me i have to get rid of that.

My assumption is that the "->SetValue" in that array is causing the
value which is overwritten to be "garbage collected". Is there a fast way to 
update the values in the array without causing such behaviour?
(there are thousands of calls to ->SetValue)

[image: Trace of execution (method is called multiple times)]
Thanks in advance,
Nicolas

```
template <typename Tnative, typename Tmanaged>
ChannelGroupData    ^   NativeToManaged(I_ChannelGroup &aChannelGroup, unsigned int index, unsigned int count)
{
    std::map< std::string, std::vector<Tnative> > v;
    aChannelGroup.GetData(v, index, count);

    ChannelGroupData^ result = gcnew ChannelGroupData(v.size());

    for (std::map< std::string, std::vector<Tnative> >::const_iterator cMIt = v.begin(); cMIt != v.end(); ++cMIt)
    {   
        std::string channelObjectPath(cMIt->first);
        I_Channel *aChannel = aChannelGroup.GetChannelByObjectPath(channelObjectPath);
        if (aChannel != NULL)
        {
            unsigned int vSize (cMIt->second.size());
            DataType aType = static_cast<DataType>(aChannel->GetDataType());
            int iIndex (0);
            const std::vector<Tnative> *pChannelDataV (&cMIt->second);
            array<Tmanaged>^ vResult = gcnew array<Tmanaged>(pChannelDataV->size());
            for (std::vector<Tnative>::const_iterator cDIt = pChannelDataV->begin(); cDIt != pChannelDataV->end(); ++cDIt, ++iIndex)
            {
                vResult->SetValue((Tmanaged)(gcnew Tnative(*cDIt)), iIndex);
            }
            result->AppendDataToChannel(gcnew System::String(channelObjectPath.c_str()), vResult,static_cast<int>( aType), iIndex);
            delete aChannel;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How significant is that 50%, though? Does it scale linearly with much larger source data buffer sizes? Is it large compared to the overhead of the rest of the application? You might not have enough profiling information here to generalise from.

Comment: When executing my program the Garbage Collection is #1 with 31,8%, User Code 25%, System Code 24%, System.IO 17%....

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption is that the "->SetValue" in that array is causing the value which is overwritten to be "garbage collected".

There's no issue with that here: You're calling `SetValue` on a new array, so each element is at its default value. If `Tmanaged` is a reference type, then the default value was null, and there's nothing to collect. If `Tmanaged` is a value type, they don't get garbage collected at all.

Offhand, I see two issues with your code:

```
for (std::vector<Tnative>::const_iterator cDIt ...)
{
    vResult->SetValue((Tmanaged)(gcnew Tnative(*cDIt)), iIndex);
}
```

- You're calling `gcnew` on `Tnative`. If it is native, wouldn't `new` be more appropriate?
- You've already got a `Tnative` object; it's in the vector that you're iterating. Why are you constructing another?

---

That said, I don't think there's an issue with your code; I think the GC is functioning properly.

Let's think about how the GC works: It has a big collection of objects, which it stores in three buckets. Newly allocated objects go into the "Gen0" bucket, then they move to the "Gen1" and "Gen2" buckets as they survive garbage collection.

As new objects are allocated, they're placed in Gen 0. When Gen 0 fills up, the GC does a collection of Gen 0. Any objects that are no longer in use are collected, any objects that are still in use move to Gen 1. (When Gen 1 fills up, the process happens there. I forget what the trigger condition for a Gen 2 collection is.)

So, in your method, you're allocating a bunch of new objects. (`gcnew ChannelGroupData(v.size())`, `gcnew array<Tmanaged>(pChannelDataV->size())`, `gcnew Tnative(*cDIt)`, and `gcnew System::String`.) Depending on how much data you have, it seems entirely likely that you're allocating enough new objects that Gen 0 fills up, and the GC does a Gen 0 collection.

I found [a blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations/) on MSDN that talks about the sizes of the GC's generations. According to that, the size of the generations can vary based on what runtime you're using, but 64 MB for Gen 0 was a typical value as of when the post was written.

When you read your data from disk, then the Gen 0 bucket fills up, and the garbage collector will kick in and do a Gen 0 collection. **This is normal behavior when allocating a lot of new memory.** Plus, if the data you're reading from disk is larger than 64 MB, then all of the objects will survive into Gen 1, and that'll trigger a Gen 1 collection! They'll survive into Gen 2, and you might end up with a Gen 2 collection as well, and those are more expensive than the Gen 0 and Gen 1.

If you really don't want a GC to happen while you're reading in the data, then I'd take a strategy of preallocation: Allocate all the managed objects you're going to need ahead of time, let the GC do its thing because you allocated all that new memory, and then keep the objects around for a long time. When you read the data from disk, replace the values on your already allocated managed objects, and the GC won't have any reason to run.